# Pine Script strategy entry strategy close

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Good afternoon, I'm using this strategy and I would like it to close the open order before opening the next one. I'm trying to automate the signals by webhook, and it sends the buy and sell signal but it doesn't finish one before opening the other.

```
//@version=4
strategy("SuperTrend Cryptobase", overlay=true)
Periods = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10)
src = input(hl2, title="Source")
Multiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)
changeATR= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
showsignals = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=false)
highlighting = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
barcoloring = input(title="Bar Coloring On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
atr2 = sma(tr, Periods)
atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2
up=src-(Multiplier*atr)
up1 = nz(up[1],up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up
dn=src+(Multiplier*atr)
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title="Up Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(5, 102, 86))
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title="UpTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(5, 102, 86), transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title="Comprar", text="Comprar", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(5, 102, 86), textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title="Down Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51))
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title="DownTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51), transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title="Vender", text="Vender", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51), textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
longFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == 1 ? color.rgb(5, 102, 86, 95) : color.white) : color.white
shortFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == -1 ? color.rgb(178, 40, 51, 95) : color.white) : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title="UpTrend Highligter", color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title="DownTrend Highligter", color=shortFillColor)
FromMonth = input(defval = 9, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
FromDay   = input(defval = 1, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2018, title = "From Year", minval = 999)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 1, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay     = input(defval = 1, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
ToYear    = input(defval = 9999, title = "To Year", minval = 999)
start     = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)       
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false

//Alerts
alertcondition(buySignal, title="SuperTrend Compra", message="SuperTrend Compra!")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="SuperTrend Venda", message="SuperTrend Venda!")

longCondition = buySignal
if (longCondition)
    strategy.close("short", comment = "Short fechado")
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = window(),comment="long")


shortCondition = sellSignal
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.close("long", comment = "Long fechado")
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, when = window(),comment="short")

buy1= barssince(buySignal)
sell1 = barssince(sellSignal)
color1 = buy1[1] < sell1[1] ? color.rgb(5, 102, 86) : buy1[1] > sell1[1] ? color.rgb(178, 40, 51) : na
barcolor(barcoloring ? color1 : na)
```

I added the strategy.close("long", comment = "Long fechado"), I need it to close a little before giving a new buy or sell signal and not on the same candle.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it by using :

```
strategy.opentrades
```

which is the number of position entry which remain opened.

You can modify your script this way, for the 'long' part :

```
var ToLong = false
var ToShort = false

if ToLong // We decided to long on the previous candle
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = window(),comment="long")
    ToLong := false
    ToShort := false
    
if (longCondition)
    ToLong := true
    ToShort := false
    if strategy.opentrades.size < 0 // a short remain open
        strategy.close("short", comment = "Short fechado")
        // We must remember to open a Long on the next candle
        ToLong := true
        ToShort := false
```

The script is executed once on each candle close, so the first time you have longCondition == true, the script will close the short only and pass Tolong to true.
On the next candle, with ToLong==true, the long will be opened.

You must follow the same logic for the 'short' part.

Your code will look like that :

```
//@version=5
strategy('SuperTrend Cryptobase', overlay=true)
Periods = input(title='ATR Period', defval=10)
src = input(hl2, title='Source')
Multiplier = input.float(title='ATR Multiplier', step=0.1, defval=3.0)
changeATR = input(title='Change ATR Calculation Method ?', defval=true)
showsignals = input(title='Show Buy/Sell Signals ?', defval=false)
highlighting = input(title='Highlighter On/Off ?', defval=true)
barcoloring = input(title='Bar Coloring On/Off ?', defval=true)
atr2 = ta.sma(ta.tr, Periods)
atr = changeATR ? ta.atr(Periods) : atr2
up = src - Multiplier * atr
up1 = nz(up[1], up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? math.max(up, up1) : up
dn = src + Multiplier * atr
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? math.min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title='Up Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(5, 102, 86))
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title='UpTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(5, 102, 86), transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title='Comprar', text='Comprar', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(5, 102, 86), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), transp=0)
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title='Down Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51))
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title='DownTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51), transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title='Vender', text='Vender', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), transp=0)
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title='', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
longFillColor = highlighting ? trend == 1 ? color.rgb(5, 102, 86, 95) : color.white : color.white
shortFillColor = highlighting ? trend == -1 ? color.rgb(178, 40, 51, 95) : color.white : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title='UpTrend Highligter', color=longFillColor, transp=90)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title='DownTrend Highligter', color=shortFillColor, transp=90)
FromMonth = input.int(defval=9, title='From Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
FromDay = input.int(defval=1, title='From Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
FromYear = input.int(defval=2018, title='From Year', minval=999)
ToMonth = input.int(defval=1, title='To Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
ToDay = input.int(defval=1, title='To Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
ToYear = input.int(defval=9999, title='To Year', minval=999)
start = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)
finish = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)
window() =>
    time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false

//Alerts
alertcondition(buySignal, title='SuperTrend Compra', message='SuperTrend Compra!')
alertcondition(sellSignal, title='SuperTrend Venda', message='SuperTrend Venda!')

longCondition = buySignal
shortCondition = sellSignal

var ToLong = false
var ToShort = false

if ToLong // We decided to long on the previous candle
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = window(),comment="long")
    ToLong := false
    ToShort := false

if ToShort
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, when = window(),comment="short")
    ToLong := false
    ToShort := false
    
if (longCondition)
    ToLong := true
    ToShort := false
    if strategy.opentrades != 0
        if strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades-1) < 0 // a short remain open
            strategy.close("short", comment = "Short fechado")
            // We must remember to open a Long on the next candle
            ToLong := true
            ToShort := false

if (shortCondition)
    ToLong := false
    ToShort := true
    if strategy.opentrades != 0
        if strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades-1) > 0 // a long remain open
            strategy.close("short", comment = "Short fechado")
            // We must remember to open a Long on the next candle
            ToLong := false
            ToShort := true

buy1 = ta.barssince(buySignal)
sell1 = ta.barssince(sellSignal)
color1 = buy1[1] < sell1[1] ? color.rgb(5, 102, 86) : buy1[1] > sell1[1] ? color.rgb(178, 40, 51) : na
barcolor(barcoloring ? color1 : na)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i can't adapt it in my code, could you show me how the full code would look like? thank you very much.

Comment: @Guilomaker I edit my answer, tell me if it is ok for you.